# How does one convert Local<Name> to a string?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

So after being away awhile some things changed.  I used to be able to do this:

```
void ObjectTemplateProxy::GetProperty(Local<String> hName, const PropertyCallbackInfo<Value>& info)
{
    auto hStr = hName->ToString();
```

But now I need an isolate, and the parameter type changed to `Local<Name>`. Then I tried this:

```
auto hStr = hName->ToString(info.GetIsolate());
```

But this still doesn't work because `hStr` is null.  It is null because, as it turns out, the name is actually a `Symbol` type and NOT `String`. I don't see any way to convert a symbol to a string, which I need to do to send the name to the C# CLR via P/Invoke to pull the value from a dictionary using string keys.

Answer (score 0):

So, it would seem that there is a `Name()` function on the `Symbol` type that returns a `String`.  I was looking for a function on the `Symbol` type and didn't find one (must have missed it). The code that worked was `hName.As<Symbol>()->Name().As<String>();`.

As noted below in the comments, `Symbol()` is not required to have a name, so beware!

Comment: Note that JavaScript Symbols are not required to have a name (or other string representation), which is why the V8 API can't provide such a conversion either. You could have: `var s = Symbol(); var t = Symbol(); var o = {}; o[s] = 42; o[t] = 123;`. If you call `hName.As<Symbol>()->Name().As<String>() you'll get "undefined" (or a crash) for both `s` and `t`. You'll need your own Symbol->String conversion in a way that makes sense for your application.

Comment: Given I have to marshal it to the CLR side for a string dictionary lookup at the moment I'm going to enforce a name requirement, but thanks for the heads up.  I will have to add this to my `TODO:` list and review later lol. ;)